# Symfony Date Constraint does not allow missing field even though the field is not required

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints

I am instantiating a constraint collection here to validate my request body for an API I am building. My idea is to validate the *birthdate* param only for its format, I don't need it to be required. The issue I am having is that, when I do not pass the *birthdate* in the request body, It throws a missing field error. Basically it treats it as a required field.
I don't know why.

```
$constraint = new Collection([
  'fields' => [
    'birthdate' => [
      new Date(message: 'Please use YYYY-MM-DD format!'),
    ],
  ],
  'allowMissingFields' => false,
  'allowExtraFields' => true,
]);
```

Comment: Don't forget tu set `'required' => false` because it's true by default

Comment: @jean-max thanks. Yes the `Date` constraint needs to be wrapped inside an Optional one. ex: `new Optional([new Date()])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't cross my mind at first, but following @jean-max comment I figured that you should make a field optional in this case because the default config is *required*. So yeah this is the answer:

```
$constraint = new Collection([
  'fields' => [
    'birthdate' => [
      new Optional([
         new Date(message: 'Please use YYYY-MM-DD format!'),
      ]),
    ],
  ],
  'allowMissingFields' => false,
  'allowExtraFields' => true,
]);
```